# Not Encoding URL Parameters with retrofit returns a strange response

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, moshi

I'm implementing an android application with Retrofit requests and Moshi to parse the response.

For one of the requests I need Retrofit to not encode the Query, because it includes "**:**" and the server won't accept "**%3A**". I use:

```
@Query(value = "viaList", encoded = true) viaCitiesCode: String
```

And

```
private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .build()
```

And "**:**" stays in the URL as it should but instead of getting a JSON response it returns this response (I didn't post the whole response displayed by Network Profile, because of its size):

> ‹      ìZ]rÛ8¾JŠû6k©ÀÒo EËŒ#Ù´${œ©©$Ñ4G©éÐNÖ—Ø[
> ìÃ^ao³{
> Žm€”HJÔŸ'N¦¦”¸,³4»ûk �Oøå+?N§dþÌ�~åÆîÜÿìŽoHðèÆTàÇg$N¸ÓdþèžÀ“ùà’Yñh‘ø9{z9áfsäÒA÷dŸš*£nô@æ<IšŠ O%$èûS�ðŠvÂ=D�sx‘pÂMýð1¡/•@<öã„„T›,+M  ÆÍIß»´/ÇsÐÁ�‘yÒKHâG!ÈúÑä99™ƒ$(.c2!Ë�s·E73€¯7ßô>/œ"?M„ÐÇBÏ†ÎYê¼ÔM�£Š
> TB{
> s/´[Bü <øâŽÝ'îg¦Úá}”!�ëÊ_»Ð·”_$¹�æSÚ¦@CHX¿e ¦Ñc˜´J¯Jžg´eÑž¡ór²lÍa*Ú)^KåÝ(l\»±;‡Üà^~] úÁ¡õž1…ŸAä' GÊ]²t)$V8ÎÇ�, €Ñ~X¸óþú
> ]ïÁ' Ò ßu£/ÑÔçX^ÌòÜÝÜé� ¨TÍãtèÎ)lì1N¢M­jf    MÞÏâüµ.EÜEADý ñ2eî…F-‡�_ƒ/‡}ž: Šd(A'eL‹î’´kµˆ õ¹±ÈëÕ0¿ˆL¸‡‹ç(‰´÷;°å]×�üžø¨Cd{÷TBljk0 ò‚PA©š©UPv£ °…Òü©‹g–Ù4ßç$…¥€PÝ±Kæ£‡~­bæƒCÐ!G!}uB†mèÁ¢Jÿ‹›©àn&7’C, s¦÷mwÌ™g¡Ë4meŸ‘5Ù†“bøw1Å}G5½«÷Ø±Lìt [
> çØñ Ó³¯œdüÉºøù“žÞÞ¤ÎEpÛûbàßo7Ý·}�Ê>

Everything works fine in Insomnia when I send the URL by disabling the URL encoding.

Thanks for your help and let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Try to change response to catch full response (I think you can use BasicResponse as response parameter or something like that), instead of converting it to the your class, to see is everything ok. And if yes, than the problem is probably with with MoshiConverterFactory, so you can also try GSON instead.

Comment: @BrankoRiznić BasicResponse works perfectly, it might be an issue according to Moshi Converter

Comment: GSON worked for me after correcting an Issue in the data class

Comment: So now with GSON everything works as expected?

Comment: Yes it does, but it also works with Moshi after making some optional paramters nullable after I have found out that they are optional in Json response (e.g. val departureTime: String?). I'll continue using moshi, because it was my mistake. Thank you!